# Exclude first image from a Woocommerce image gallery

Tags: images, woocommerce-offtopic, gallery, exclude

I would like to exclude the first image from the image gallery (this is not the featured image of the product) of a single product page in Woocommerce.

I'm not an expert on PHP but, could an array_shift do the trick?

Here you can find the exact example: https://www.superflua.es/catalogo/saint-laurent-chico-malo/

I would like to prevent the first image (with the red background) from showing. I can't delete the image from the gallery because I need it there for another action from another plugin.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

I've already solved this issue. The solution I found is not really good, but it did the job. I had only two images in my gallery and I wanted to hide the first one, so I used

```
array_reverse();
```

where my template loaded the images for the gallery and I hid the arrows to go from one image from another and the slider with the thumbnails. It's not the perfect solution, but it's working for now.

Thanks!